# Injected dependencies not accessible in class methods for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6 classes for Angular controllers and I'm running into a slight annoyance with dependency injection. Take this controller, for example (obviously not a real class).

```
class PersonController {
  constructor(MyDependency) {
    MyDependency.test(); // this works
  }

  sendEvent() {
    MyDependency.test(); // MyDependency is undefined
  }
}

PersonController.$inject = ['MyDependency'];

export default PersonController;
```

When the constructor is run, the dependency is found fine. However if I call the `sendEvent` method (or any other class method), the dependency is no longer defined. I've gotten around this before by just attaching it to `this` in the constructor e.g. `this.MyDependency = MyDependency;`.

Is there any other way that this can be achieved without hanging the dependency off `this`?

Comment: If you only can inject it into instances, then no there is no way around that.

Comment: Why are you afraid of using `this`. This is straightforward and common way to save some arguments from constructor

Comment: @just-boris I have no issue with using `this` and I have every time I've had to do this, I was just wondering if there was any other 'accepted' way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no other way to do this, so I will stick to using `this`!

Answer (score 1):

It is because myDependency is not accessible in your methods. Do this.myDependency  = myDependency in the constructor and then do this.my dependency.test() in your method.

EDIT: Below is an alternative approach:-

```
let _myDependency;    
class PersonController {
  constructor(MyDependency) {
    _myDependency = MyDependency;
    _myDependency.test(); // this works
 }

sendEvent() {
    _myDependency.test(); // this will work
  }
}
```

Another ways to emulate private properties are :- using Symbols/weakmaps or creating a closure around the whole class and store MyDependency within this closure.

Comment: Sorry, was too quick to answer. Didn't see that you are asking for an alternative to this approach

Comment: Using global variable is not good idea to expose injectables. It will be rewritten with every call of constructor

Comment: True but also depends on what kind of value you are storing. For something like http, if you dont want it to be attached to this, there is no problem in thus approach. It won't pollute the global scope as it is in an ES6 module. As I also mentioned, another approach is to use symbols/weakmaps.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, personally I don't think there is anything particularly wrong in attaching the dependency to this.