# ES6: what is equivalent of _this / self

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Am trying to get my head around ES6 and Angular by converting an existing app. Unsurprisingly, the challenge is `this`!

The `let _$localStorage` came from  ([Injected dependencies not accessible in class methods for AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422360/injected-dependencies-not-accessible-in-class-methods-for-angularjs)) but there was already a suggestion there that it was not a good way.

The next thing I tried to implement had the same issue, namely how to have global variables within a class.

Would welcome advice

```
let _$localStorage;
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class MainSvc {
    constructor($http, $localStorage) {
        this.$http = $http;
        _$localStorage = $localStorage;

        this.data = {};
      //^^^^^^^^
        this.production = (location.host === "afbackend.herokuapp.com");
        this.baseUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;

        console.log('MainSvc');
    }

    login(data, success, error) {
        this.$http.post(this.baseUrl + '/auth', data)
        .success(function(res)  {
            console.log("Login succeeded, token :", res.token);
            _$localStorage.token = res.token;
            this.data.user = getUserFromToken(res.token);
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            console.log(m);
            // success();
        })
        // .error(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of 'this' has not changed with es6.

The only thing that is different in regards to this, is when you use [big arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

With big arrow, 'this' is passed along from the calling function to the called function(same as binding the function to this).

So your still free to use this in a class, but remember that when you use regular anonymous functions that are not big arrow, you still need to pass along 'this' if you want to access it.

So to correct your code, you should write.

```
login(data, success, error) {
     var self = this;
        this.$http.post(this.baseUrl + '/auth', data)
        .success(function(res)  {
            console.log("Login succeeded, token :", res.token);
            _$localStorage.token = res.token;
            self.data.user = getUserFromToken(res.token);
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            console.log(m);
            // success();
        })
        // .error(error);
    }
```

Which could also, using big arrow, be expressed as:

```
    login(data, success, error) {
        this.$http.post(this.baseUrl + '/auth', data)
        .success((res) => { //Big arrow
            console.log("Login succeeded, token :", res.token);
            _$localStorage.token = res.token;
            this.data.user = getUserFromToken(res.token);
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            console.log(m);
            // success();
        })
        // .error(error);
    }
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense except that I have to declare self in any method with callbacks...

Comment: In fact the benefit of the thick air functions becomes very clear even in my simple examples. No `self` needed really